# NodeJs Check Phase called before timer phase done

Tags: javascript, node.js, event-loop

```
In first case, NodeJs cexecutes the "Timer" phase and then "Check" phase.
But
In Second case, it comes to "Timer" phase and before it completes it goes to "Check" phase and then "Timer" phase as Event loop says.

In second case Why it leaves the Timer phase before completes?
```

https://ibb.co/pdfjBRX

```js
// Case 1
for (let i = 0; i < 10e2; i++) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("timer:", i);
  }, 0);

  setImmediate(() => {
    console.log("check", i)
  })
}
// Case 2
setTimeout(() => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10e2; i++) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("timer:", i);
    }, 0);

    setImmediate(() => {
      console.log("check", i)
    })
  }
}, 500);
```

Comment: Please replace the image with actual code.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Seems like something makes lib_uv loop at ms boundaries. SO when your timeouts callbacks have been running for more than one ms, that loop will end, execute the immediate callbacks and then come back to the remaining timeouts (You can store `process.hrtime()` and see that when the immediate start executing is always when switching from one ms to an other. Now I can't find why it doesn't do this at init...

Comment: Yes, when i run the code on repl.it, it works as expected but pn windows it does not. The timers call first then check and again timer